# How to submit changes for Blender's online documentation?

Tags: documentation

I often refer to https://docs.blender.org/api when I'm working on scripts.  I also often find that there are places where the documentation is unclear or even incorrect.  I was wondering if there was any way to submit proposed changes to the documentation, kind of like a Wikipedia page?

Comment: https://www.blender.org/get-involved/

Comment: I downloaded the manual, but can't find the API pages.  I searched every *.rst document for ```ray_cast```, but had no hits.